# angular2 "400 Bad Request" on POST Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

When I do a POST I get the error POST http://localhost:5000/api/activities 400 (Bad Request)
But when I add a id my put works perfect.

Can somebody help me, I don't find the solution. Why do I get the 400 (Bad Request) Error?

Here is my code:

in global:

```
BASE_URL_API = 'http://localhost:5000/api/'
```

in activitiy.service.ts

```
private activitiesUrl = this.globals.BASE_URL_API + 'activities';

//POST
private post(activity: Activity): Promise<Activity> {
let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

return this.http
  .post(this.activitiesUrl, JSON.stringify(activity), { headers: headers })
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().data)
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
// Update existing Activity
private put(activity: Activity): Promise<Activity> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  let url = `${this.activitiesUrl}/${activity.id}`;

  return this.http
    .put(url, JSON.stringify(activity), { headers: headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => activity)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

in addActivity.ts

```
activityCredentials = {
id: null,
name: 'test', 
description: 'test description',
locationId: 2,
activityTypeId: 2,
};

... 

public save(){
    this.activityService.save(this.activityCredentials).then(success => {
     if (success) {
        this.createSuccess = true;
          this.showPopup("Success", "Activity added.");
      } else {
        this.showPopup("Error", "Problem adding activities.");
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.showPopup("Error", error);
    });
  }
```

in ASP.NET API

```
[HttpPost(Name = "CreateActivity")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateActivity([FromBody] Activity item)
       {
           if(item == null)
           {
               return BadRequest();
           }

          ApplicationDbContext.Activities.Add(item);
           await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

           return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetActivityById", new { Controller = "ActivitiesController", activityId = item.Id }, item);
       }

       [HttpPut("{activityId:int}", Name = "UpdateActivity")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateActivity(Int16 activityId, [FromBody] Activity item)
       {
           if(item == null || item.Id != activityId)
           {
               return BadRequest();
           }

           var model = await ApplicationDbContext.Activities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == activityId);

           if(model == null)
           {
               var msg = String.Format(FAILGETENTITYBYID, activityId);
               return NotFound(msg);
           }

           model.Name = item.Name;
           model.Description = item.Description;
           model.LocationId = item.LocationId;
           model.ActivityTypeId = item.ActivityTypeId;

           ApplicationDbContext.Activities.Attach(model);
           ApplicationDbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
           await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

           return new NoContentResult();
       }
```

I don't get the problem. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Check the JSON.stringify(activity) object whether it's passing param's or not

Comment: @Vignesh JSON.stringify(activity) is passing param's

Comment: You're sending lowercase `is`, while on the server you access `Id` with uppercase i. Please check if that's the issue.

Comment: @AlexFlorin I've changed it but it still doesn't work. When I add an id to my request it works perfectly with put. So I think that it can't be a problem with the param's?

Comment: `400 (Bad Request)` means your request doesn't even leave the client application. Perhaps you can investigate what happens behind `.post()` method or update your question with a `console.log()` on the `activity` object. Also, as far as I know, there's no need to srtingify it. Have you tried sending the activity object directly? (Without the `JSON.stringify()` call).

Comment: @AlexFlorin Deleting JSON.stringify () doesn't resolve the issue. I debug and activity object looks correct. 
Post shows: url = "http://localhost:5000/api/activities/2", activity = Object {id: 2, name: "test", description: "test description", locationId: 2, activityTypeId: 2}, headers = Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}

See image: 
https://s10.postimg.org/5ho3lusjd/Schermafbeelding_2017-07-21_om_15.26.12.png

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your problem and this is the end result:

- Here is the ActivitiesService:

```js
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs';

class Activity {
  id: null;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  locationId: number;
  activityTypeId: number;
};

@Injectable()
export class ActivitiesService {
  private activitiesUrl = 'http://ask-around.ngenh.com:6543/api/auth';

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  //POST
  public post(activity: Activity): Promise<Activity> {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let url = this.activitiesUrl + '/login';

    return this.http
      .post(url, activity, { headers: headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json().data
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
   }

  // Update existing Activity
  public put(activity: Activity): Promise<Activity> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let url = `${this.activitiesUrl}/${activity.id}`;

    return this.http
      .put(url, activity, { headers: headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json().data
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  handleError(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Then you just provide it into a module and use it like you'd use any other service. The link I've provided is a public API of mine and you can see it returns `500 Internal server error` because it can't handle the input.

Observations:

- your `post` and `put` methods were private (this shouldn't affect anything)
- the arrow function provided to the `then` method was different

Other than this, I can't think of anything else that might cause the trouble for you. If it's still not working, please try to replicate the problem in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or something similar and then update your question with it.